# java.io.File.isFile() returning false on a mapped drive file, however cmd is able to list the contents

Tags: java, windows, ifs

Created a Mapped Drive [Z:], which is created against a IBMi share by the command

> NET USE Z: \IBMiMachine\PROD /USER:USER1 *******

The drive is created successfully.

Then tried to list all files (e.g. .php/.txt/.html etc) present under the mapped drive, by a simple Java program (using Java 7 IO APIs, and the Java class resides in a runnable jar **myjar.jar**) by running the command

> java -jar myjar.jar Z:

So noticed that **java.io.File.isFile()** returning the false against the various file:

```
File: 'Z:\ABC\20100709\Info.php'
isSymbolicLink -- false
isDirectory -- true
exists: true
is file: false
can read: true
can write: true
is hidden: false


File: 'Z:\ZYZ\20100607\intranet\Int.php'
isSymbolicLink -- false
isDirectory -- true
exists: true
is file: false
can read: true
can write: true
is hidden: false
```

also the **java.io.File.isDirectory()** also saying those are directories; But those files contents can be seen on command prompt by the command "CAT <file_name>".

My Java Program code like this:

```
private static int counter = 1;
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    if (Utils.length(args) == 0)
    {
        print("Either passed argument was empty or null: " + Arrays.toString(args));
        return;
    }

    print("Passed argument was: " + Arrays.toString(args));

    doFile(new File(args[0]));
}

private static void doFile(File folder)
{
    if (folder.isDirectory())
    {
        showFileAttributes1(folder);
        showFileAttributes2(folder);

        String files[] = folder.list();
        int length = (files == null) ? 0 : files.length;
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
            doFile(new File(folder, files[i]));
        }
    }
    else if (folder.isFile())
    {
        showFileAttributes1(folder);
        showFileAttributes2(folder);
    }
}

private static void showFileAttributes1(File folder) throws IOException
{
   print("");
   print(" " + counter++ + ". File: '" + folder.getPath() + "' ---------");
    Map<String, Object> fileAttributes = Files.readAttributes(folder.toPath(), "*");
    Iterator<String> iterator = fileAttributes.keySet().iterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext())
    {
        String key = iterator.next();
        print(key + " -- " + fileAttributes.get(key));
    }
}

private static void showFileAttributes2(File file) throws IOException
{
    print("exists: " + file.exists());
    print("is file: " + file.isFile());
    print("can read: " + file.canRead());
    print("can execute: " + file.canExecute());
    print("can write: " + file.canWrite());
    print("is hidden: " + file.isHidden());
    
    Path filePath = Paths.get(file.getAbsolutePath());

    //Is file readable
    boolean isReadable = Files.isReadable(filePath);
    print("Is file readable: " + isReadable);

    //Is file writable
    boolean isWritable = Files.isWritable(filePath);
    print("Is file writable: " + isWritable);

    //Is file executable
    boolean isExecutable = Files.isExecutable(filePath);
    print("Is file executable: " + isExecutable);
}

private static void print(String message)
{
    System.out.println(message);
}
```

What approach can be taken to overcome of Java problem??

**Note:** I have the same full access rights on that machine/folder, since by the **ROBOCOPY** command I am able to copy complete folder structure of mapped drive into my local drive, and then no issue of Java API on that folder then

> ROBOCOPY Z: C:\mysource *.php /E /log:log.txt

Comment: You should provide JDK details, for example is it OpenJDK ? What is the precise version (including minor version) and so on.

Comment: It's a Orcale JDK 1.7 basically, But I also tried in JDK 1.8...but same issue found.

Comment: Your code does not print "File: '...'", yet you show that line in its output. So the output and the code don't correspond. How do you know you are running the same code that you show us?

Comment: You will get more reliable results using the [java.nio.file](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/package-summary.html) package instead of the ancient java.io.File class.

Comment: @k314159 ...Update the Java code...check once gain..